# Change Size of Jpeg File in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I need to transfer some images through Network, I saved images with Jpeg and 40% quality as following:

```
public void SaveJpeg(string path, Image image, int quality) {
        if((quality < 0) || (quality > 100)) {
            string error = string.Format("Jpeg image quality must be
 between 0 and 100, with 100 being the highest quality.  A value of {0} was
 specified.", quality);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(error);
        }
        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new
 EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
        ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        image.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
    }
```

But with this way the size of Jpeg files not enough small, Also I change the quality but that's not good appearance. Is there any way to save pictures with smaller file size and proper appearance? I don't know but is there any way to use `System.Drawing.Graphics` object, also I don't need to zip files, or change dimension of images, at now just the size of picture file is important.

Comment: Can you make the width and height smaller or must the picture dimensions remain the same?

Comment: @Jason Down No, I hope to find a way without change dimension

Comment: Well there really are only three ways to decrease the size of the file. Decrease quality, decrease the dimensions or change the format to something else with a better compression ratio (not sure of any way to do this in .Net other than the usual choices).

Answer (score 2):

With image compression, there's a fine line between creating a small file and creating a poor quality image. JPEG is a lossy compression format which means that data is removed when compressed, which is why constantly re-encoding a JPEG file will continually decrease its quality.

On the other hand, PNG files are lossless but may still result in bigger files. You could try encoding the file as a PNG using [PngBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970062.aspx). This will ensure the quality remains high, but the size may or may not decrease enough for your program (it depends on the image).

If you're performing this on a local machine and don't need to do it too often (e.g. for many concurrent users), you could invoke an external program to do it for you. [PNG Monster](http://www.vbgore.com/PNG_Monster) is very good at compressing PNG files without decreasing the quality. You could call this from your program and send the resulting PNG file. (You may want to check the licensing terms to ensure that it's compatible with your program).

There aren't many ways where you can maintain a high quality and perform a high compression at the same time, without manipulating the image (e.g. changing dimension).

Answer (score 0):

I have a method for creating and saving the thumbnail of an uploaded picture, I think `NewImageSize` method might help you.It also handles the quality issue.

```
public Size NewImageSize(int OriginalHeight, int OriginalWidth, double FormatSize)
        {
            Size NewSize;
            double tempval;

            if (OriginalHeight > FormatSize && OriginalWidth > FormatSize)
            {
                if (OriginalHeight > OriginalWidth)
                    tempval = FormatSize / Convert.ToDouble(OriginalHeight);
                else
                    tempval = FormatSize / Convert.ToDouble(OriginalWidth);

                NewSize = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(tempval * OriginalWidth), Convert.ToInt32(tempval * OriginalHeight));
            }
            else
                NewSize = new Size(OriginalWidth, OriginalHeight); return NewSize;
        } 

        private bool save_image_with_thumb(string image_name, string path)
        {

                ResimFileUpload1.SaveAs(path + image_name + ".jpg"); //normal resim kaydet



            ///////Thumbnail yarat ve kaydet//////////////
            try
            {
                Bitmap myBitmap;

                myBitmap = new Bitmap(path + image_name + ".jpg");

                Size thumbsize = NewImageSize(myBitmap.Height, myBitmap.Width, 100);

                System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallBack = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

                // If jpg file is a jpeg, create a thumbnail filename that is unique.

                string sThumbFile = path + image_name + "_t.jpg";

                // Save thumbnail and output it onto the webpage

                System.Drawing.Image myThumbnail = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(thumbsize.Width, thumbsize.Height, myCallBack, IntPtr.Zero);

                myThumbnail.Save(sThumbFile);

                // Destroy objects
                myThumbnail.Dispose();
                myBitmap.Dispose();

                return true;
            }
            catch //yaratamazsa normal ve thumb iptal
            {
                return false;
            }
            ///////////////////////////////////

        }
```